# Specify Postgres version in ActiveRecord config

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have multiple versions of PostgreSQL running on my machine (running Ubuntu Trusty).

```
$ service postgresql status
9.1/main (port 5433): online
9.5/main (port 5432): online
```

I am running several Ruby apps with ActiveRecord, that are each using different versions of Postgres, and I want to be able to specify the Postgres version in `database.yml`, something like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  version: 9.1
  # ... or, since this seems to be close to pg_wrapper's syntax:
  cluster: 9.1/main
```

What I *don't* want to have to do is specify `port: 5433`, since that's likely to be different for each version on each machine it's running on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why keep database connection details in version control in the first place? IMO `. gitignore` it and have everyone fill it in with their own details or set `DATABASE_URL` in the environment.

Comment: Yeah, great, cos they're all *sure* to get all the details right.

Comment: They probably know their machines better, right? This cluster-thingy, as far as I know, is Debian-specific. Are you expecting everyone to be on Debian (or derivatives, like Ubuntu)? Also note that `pg_wrapper` only affects utilities that Rails doesn't use (probably with the exception of `pg_dump` for schema in SQL).

Answer (score 2):

You can put environment variables in your `database.yml` using a bit of ERB:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  port: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_91_PORT'] %>
```

That way your `database.yml` files are the same on your various machines and you just need to set up some machine-specific environment settings.

Comment: Hmmm... But I want to have it set once, in the repository, so I don't *have* to keep setting it up on every machine.

Comment: I don't think you can, Rails isn't going to know how to figure out which versions of PostgreSQL are running and which ports they're using on any random machine; suppose you have an Ubuntu box, a Debian box, a couple macs, how do you expect Rails to know what is running where? Environment variables are the standard way of doing this sort of thing, most apps I build end up with a handful of environment variables to deal with the differences between different developer machines, staging servers, and production servers.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned, there's `pg_wrapper`. Any Postgres command line script can take the option `--cluster=9.1/main` and choose the right service. Why not ActiveRecord's adapter?

Comment: You're welcome to submit a patch to Rails if setting environment variables is too difficult to manage.

Comment: How about: `port: <%= \`service postgresql status\`.match(/9\.1\/main \(port (\d+)\)/)[1] %>`? (Then again, that's probably still Ubuntu-specific...)

Comment: So assuming that you have `service` in the PATH and that you're on Ubuntu is better than just setting some environment variables? You know that those backticks are going to get executed every time `database.yml` is read regardless of which environment you're in, right? I think you're wasting too much time on something that is so trivially solved.